# Encode PGP encrypted binary in base64 for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, base64

I have a PGP encrypted file called file.pgp which must not be in ascii-armor but binary. It looks like this:

```
�P��3E��Q� �i`p���
����&�9
�ֻ�<P�+�[����R0��$���q����VJ��hu���bE"2��M1r��j�K�v�@6�3E�Ҳ�A�W{Z
��FEԭ�YV��6g�V���e�,I�Zpw�r��8׆
�mc��h��n���k�p�>JH\�G�6��M1|>�G�fl�J���6��
ج��
   �_��y8�..{���_⮵���F���~�vt
                             �8AB;z����m^��Xp���VӅCzD�ճn

����{+d�3�"��N�1p�
```

When I'm using GNU base64 encoder, I'm getting this string:

`$ cat file.gpg | base64
hQEMA1DujfGcM0WiAQgAvcIMUfydsSDmaWBwnoWACrsapePpJpU5Co68276SK2XVBqY2YyNUgzAF
oawkpMjfcQS+7+nJVkrb7Gh1h4L9YkUiMo+dTTFyzs5qskuECNZ25UA2rzNF+NKyq0HZV3sXWg3P
AwZNZbNJIAc4xWlBNfsNoda7zhk8UJArj1sAiKPw5VIKjahGRdSt2FlWurs2Z5EXVriLG0aHZbAs
SeCjWnB3Aalyoo8414aGbWOr5WjU7rpugBLw52uAcJgcPkpIXMJjCEf4gTbc1k0xfD4YjUejZmyH
H0rYAAHw3DbjyQrYrLmHC9Vfm655HBU40xceLi5/e4n2Dxge+F/irrW9o9JGAfCf5OZ+gXZ0Ggv9
t620m704QUI7eryy0ddtXoGsWHCxu4gaVtOFQ3pEp9WzZghuC5j1/c57K2T4lzP+IvEfo07fMRFw
tg==`

With the GNU base64 tool, I can successfully reconvert it to the originating pgp-file and decrypt it.

I want to implement a similar tool in NodeJS. I can successfully convert ASCII text but not binary content. My provisional code looks like this:

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();
var data = "";

stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
  data += chunk;
});

stdin.on('end', function() {
    console.log(new Buffer(text, 'binary').toString('base64'));
});
```

Usage: `$ cat file.gpg | node base64.js`

The output looks different to what GNU base64 offers. Also I can't convert it back to the original file.gpg file - GnuPG can't find anything to decrypt.

Comment: I'm not sure what the final solution will be, but I think part of the problem will be that when you add `chunk` to `data`, it's being converted to a string instead of a binary.  I'm pretty sure Node has the concept of a buffer, which would be used for binary content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you pass a string and not a buffer as theGleep point in its comment.

You can do it like this:

```
let stdin = process.openStdin();
let data = [];

stdin.on('data', chunk => {
  data.push(chunk);
});

stdin.on('end', () => {
  console.log(Buffer.concat(data).toString('base64'));
});
```